# Match in an array within the current document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In an aggregation pipeline operating on documents like

```
{
    "availablePackages": [
        {
            "title": "Silver",
            "code": "001",
        },
        {
            "title": "Gold",
            "code": "002",
        },
        {
            "title": "Platinum",
            "code": "003",
        },
    "selectedPackageCode": "002"
}
```

I need to replace everything in the above document with the title of the package whose code matches the `selectedPackageCode`.  So I want to the pipeline to end up with

```
{
    "packageTitle": "Gold"
}
```

This is not a lookup, because it's in the current document.  I thought I might be able to use `$let` to create a variable and then a `$match` to find the right array element, but I have not found a syntax that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to match `availablePackages` with `selectedPackageCode` and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get first matching element. In order to make it in one aggregation stage you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    // ... other stages
    {
        $project: {
            packageTitle: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { 
                        selectedPackage: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [
                                { $filter: { input: "$availablePackages", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.code", "$selectedPackageCode" ] } } }, 0
                            ]
                        } 
                    },
                    in: "$$selectedPackage.title"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```